# Validate text area with multiple Ip adresses, one per line

Tags: php

i want to validate a Text area where the user can insert only ip adresses, one per line.
This is my simple php code when I press the button:

```
$text_area = strip_tags($_POST["text_area"]);
$file = "ip_list.txt";
file_put_contents($file, $text_area);
```

This is the text area:
[Textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDxV6.png)

Thanks

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see any attempt of validation.

Comment: I have been using php recently and I don't know how to do it. The question is: How can validation be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP form validation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945836/php-form-validation-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$ips = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST["text_area"]));
foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    $isValidIp = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
    if ($isValidIp) {
        echo 'valid Ip';
    } else {
        echo 'invalid Ip';
    }
}
```

References:

[TextArea to Array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518434/textarea-to-array-with-php)

[How do I check if a users input is a valid IP address or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211148/how-do-i-check-if-a-users-input-is-a-valid-ip-address-or-not)